# Integrating a messenging function into Phonegap-App

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

i want to integrate a small chat / instant messaging function in my app and need a little start-up aid.
I've registered a Google Cloud Messaging Account and received a configuration file ("google-services.json", containing the project id) and a server API key.

The first question is: Do i have to make further settings in my google account so that the app gets all information needed for the messenging function?

The next question is, how to integrate the messenging function in my project.

What i've done (and what seems NOT to work):

In my index.html file, i have integrated the following code (XXXXXXXXX has  been replaced with my sender ID):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="PushNotification.js"></script>
<script>
var pushNotification;

function onDeviceReady() {
    alert('Device is ready');
    try { 
        pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
        alert('Registering ' + device.platform);
        if(device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' ||device.platform == 'amazon-fireos' ) {
        pushNotification.register(
        successHandler, 
        errorHandler, 
        {
            "senderID":"XXXXXXXXXXX",
            "ecb":"onNotification"
        });  

        alert('Registered the Android device');
        alert('regID = ' + e.regid);
    } else {
        pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"});   
        alert('Registered the iOS device');
    }
    }
    catch(err) 
    { 
        txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n"; 
        txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n"; 
        //alert(txt); 
        alert('Error: ' + err.message);
    } 
}

// handle APNS notifications for iOS
function onNotificationAPN(e) {
    if(e.alert) {
         // showing an alert also requires the org.apache.cordova.dialogs plugin
          navigator.notification.alert(e.alert);
    }

    if(e.sound) {
        // playing a sound also requires the org.apache.cordova.media plugin
        var snd = new Media(e.sound);
        snd.play();
    }

    if(e.badge) {
        pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, e.badge);
    }
}

// handle GCM notifications for Android
function onNotification(e) {
    alert('EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event);
    switch( e.event )
    {
        case 'registered':
        if( e.regid.length > 0 )
        {
            // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
            // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
            console.log("regID = " + e.regid);
            alert(' REGID = ' + e.regid);
        }
        break;

        case 'message':
            // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
            // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
            if(e.foreground) {
                alert('--INLINE NOTIFICATION--');
                // on Android soundname is outside the payload. 
                // On Amazon FireOS all custom attributes are contained within payload
                 var soundfile = e.soundname || e.payload.sound;
                // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
                // playing a sound also requires the org.apache.cordova.media plugin
                var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/"+ soundfile);
                my_media.play();
            } else {   
                // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
                if(e.coldstart)
                    //$("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                    alert('--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--')
                else
                    alert('--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--')
            }
            alert('MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message);
            //android only
            alert('MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt);
            //amazon-fireos only
            alert('MESSAGE -> TIMESTAMP: ' + e.payload.timeStamp);
            break;

            case 'error':
                 //$("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
                alert('ERROR -> MSG' + e.msg);
            break;

             default:
                 //$("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is</li>');
                alert('EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is');
            break;
    }
 }

function tokenHandler (result) {
    // Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
    // here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
    alert('iOS Result = ' + result);
}

function successHandler (result) {
    alert('Android Result = ' + result);
    alert('RegID = ' + e.regid);
}

function errorHandler (error) {
    alert('Error = ' + error);
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);

alert('regID = ' + e.regid);            
alert('Reg code completed');
</script>
```

As i use Phonegab Build, i have added the following line to my config.xml file

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" version="2.4.0" />
```

The following plugins (which are also used) have been already part of the config file:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
```

My main questions are:

Where do i have to place the Server API Key?
Where do i have to place the google-services.json file (in which directory) and how is this file linked to he index.html

Further questions:
- Is the GCM Service really free? Because in the member area there is a display "Excpected fees this month: 0,00 €" --> will the fees increase?
- If a user downloads and installs my app from the playstore: How does HE get a sender ID and if i want to send him a message --> How do I know his sender ID to start messenging with him?

I haven't understood the GCM-thing in principle.
Can anyone give me a little help?

Best regards

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

The GCM service itself is free, as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm).

I'm not familiar with setting up Phonegap projects, but the `google-services.json` file was intended for use with the Google Services plugin for Gradle. Gradle itself is a build tool used by Android Studio. I'm not sure if Phonegap has a similar plugin, but in case it doesn't, what you'll be needing is the project number/sender ID. You register your app/client with that. More on this below.

You use your server API key in your server code, which is the app server that will be sending messages to your app.

More on registration. You'll need to check with some Phonegap tutorials, because GCM's new (and recommended) way for registering is through [Instance IDs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register). It still uses the same sender ID, but you'll need to interface with Google Play Services to do this.